# ListView ItemTemplate with Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have Listview with custom item template, Image and textblock. To Listview is bound the collection. When I fill up the collection, the items are rendered, but images cause, that rows jumps for a while (hope, you understand, what I mean). If I remove image from item template, everything works fine, the items are normally rendered. This is my item template xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactItemDataTemplate" x:DataType="contactData:Contact">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--<Image Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MainImage" Source="{x:Bind ImageStatusUri, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,8,12,8">

                </Image>-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Nickname}" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Grid>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" StrokeThickness="0.4" Height="0.4"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="#D1D3D4"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**UPDATE:**
I resolved it. I've set MinHeight for the row, and it's ok now. Thank you for your help and time :)

Comment: are the images local on the computer or is they downloaded from web ? and when loading in cause the "jump" ?

Comment: images are localy. directly in solution.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots that show the "jumping" ?

Comment: I'd like to, but I can't. It's commercial app :(

Comment: Could you try to describe it a little more detailed then?

Comment: How many rows do you load? I guess it's resizing the columns on it's content -> this you could mean by flickering. just a guess...

Comment: I don't how many row. It depends. When data are loaded, I can see, how margins are applied.

Comment: 48x48. I've tried to remove margins from image and problem has disappeared. But I need margins.